# Hurdles in Migrating from nginx to haproxy?

Tags: ssl, nginx, webserver, load-balancing, haproxy

I use HAProxy for loadbalancing and behind my HAProxy is Nginx that provides only SSL Termination for me. Since HAProxy also supports SSL Termination, I want to get rid of the Nginx layer. My question is, how easy is to migrate the configuration that Nginx holds(like below) to HAProxy and also is it possible(as far as I know, it is)?. I understand the pros and cons of HAProxy and Nginx, and hence I have taken this decision.  Could anyone please point me out to a guide, that explains this or any useful insight is much appreciated. The blogs I have found on Internet just scratches this topic indirectly. My main concern is to not go back to the same infrastructure setup(i.e., HAProxy and nginx) that I currently have, only to realize later that haproxy does not support some configuration that nginx supports(the configuration exactly like below).

```
server {
  listen 10.0.9.74:8443  ssl;
  listen 10.0.9.74:8080;

  server_name example.com abc.xyz.de *.abc.xyz.de;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/xyz.de.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/xyz.de.key;
  ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  #ssl_ciphers RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  ssl_ciphers EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+RC4:EECDH:EDH+aRSA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS:+RC4:RC4;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
  ssl_session_timeout 1m;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://haproxy;
    proxy_redirect off;

  proxy_connect_timeout 300;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Connection "";

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    charset utf-8;
  }
  include /etc/nginx/snicloudssl.conf;
}
```

Comment: You nginx file is quite basic and all is portable to HAProxy. So you should just go ahead and test it. But they both have different applications. If you need to use more nginx related features in future then it would be a problem.

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yup!.. I hope i wouldn't need nginx specific features in the future.I knw HAProxy is more specialised for load balancing  and Nginx specializes as webserver and also includes load balancing with other features. Since in my case, I use nginx only for SSL termination, it motivated me to plan for its removal from my infrastructure.

Comment: If you need some help on certain options, do not hesitate to also ask on the mailing list, a lot of people there know both products very well and may give good advice. But at first glance it looks straightforward, you will probably not even need any help in the end :-)